# Box polygon rendering w/ normals showing weird lighting/coloring

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

Basically, I have 2 triangles that appear slightly different in color (looks like a lighting issue due to incorrect normals). But I don't think this is the case...

**Details**

I have a simple cube (box), where each face is composed of 6 vertices using a vertex buffer (I am not using an index buffer at the moment).

In addition to my vertices I have defined the normal values for each face.

However, it appears that something is slightly wrong with either the normals (which I don't think there is an issue with) and/or the lighting.

[image]

Each face is drawn using WebGl.drawArrays using TRIANGLE_STRIP.
The image is showing the front face of the cube.
The following are its vertices (note that the origin is the top-left corner of the front face):

```
            0, 1, 0,
            0, 0, 0,
            1, 0, 0,

            1, 0, 0,
            1, 1, 0,
            0, 1, 0
```

The following are its normals:

```
            0, 0, 1,
            0, 0, 1,
            0, 0, 1,

            0, 0, 1,
            0, 0, 1,
            0, 0, 1
```

**Question**

Any ideas why the 1st triangle is lighter in color than the 2nd triangle?

Comment: This will most likely not solve the issue but you should use TRIANGLES instead of TRIANGLE_STRIP if you have 6 vertices per face. To use TRIANGLE_STRIP you need 4 vertices, from your array they would be 1st,2nd,3rd and 5th line. Try fixing that since now you are actually drawing 4 triangles per face instead of 2.

Comment: Show us the code responsible for drawing the arrays. Even though the normal data may seem correct, it may happen that the data you pass to the shader is wrong. Share some more code, because I would bet my money on bad normal data.

Comment: @Matic. I will consider going to triangles. I use this because I want my Cube to look like a wireframe box when using LINE_STRIP (no diagonal lines).

Comment: I suspect the issue is because i have lighting enable per vertex.

Comment: This is a problem with the normals and nothing to do with your lighting method. In your text you say `I have defined the normal values for each face.` but then you show that you are passing 6 normals which is actually one normal per vertex and not per face. Also you are saying that you are using TRIANGLE_STRIPS but your data is 6 vertices (which corresponds to TRIANGLES) instead of 4 vertices. You would need to show some more code or jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

The trick with triangle strip is that each additional triangle gets one additional vertex but three normal vectors. I would guess you are not specifying enough normal vectors or specifying too many vertices.